# Trying to plot change in electricity consumption per year with R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

**EDIT:** I figured out that the year has to be of the numeric data type, or the code has to be written as:

```
ggplot(data = Electricity_Consumption_per_Capita_United_States, aes(x = year, y = value)) +
  geom_line(group = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1960, 2010, 5))
```

**Original Question:**

I downloaded the "Electricity use, per person" data set from [here](https://www.gapminder.org/data/). This is what the data frame looks like:

[image]

I am trying to plot the change in electricity consumption per person for any given country over the years in the data frame (1960 to 2011), and decided to start with the United States. I thought it made sense to use tidyr to organize the years under one column, and the actual kWh under another column:

```
Electricity_Consumption_Per_Capita <- read_excel("Datasets/Indicator_Electricity consumption per capita.xlsx")

#Gather the years and corresponding electricity consumption per capita values per country.
Electricity_Consumption_Per_Capita %>%
  gather(key = "year", value = "value", -"Electricity consumption, per capita (kWh)") -> Electricity_Consumption_Per_Capita

#Rename the Electricity consumption, per capita (kWh) variable to Country, then filter to obtain the data for the United States.
Electricity_Consumption_Per_Capita %>%
  rename(Country = `Electricity consumption, per capita (kWh)`) %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  filter(Country == "United States") -> Electricity_Consumption_per_Capita_United_States
```

The resulting data frame looks like:

[image]

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to plot the value (kWh) and the year on the same plot. I tried a normal line chart with no success:

```
ggplot(data = Electricity_Consumption_per_Capita_United_States, aes(x = "year", y = "value")) +
  geom_line()
```

I think this is a discrete versus continuous variable problem, but I'm not certain. May someone point me in the right direction? Do I have to change the "year" column, which is currently a character vector, to a date data type?

Comment: 1) what error did you get.  2) please add actual data (use `dput`), not images of data to your question

Comment: I used dput() on the data frame and it saved it into a text file. How do I show that on here?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from the aesthetics.